# How to add a notification title when the iPhone is locked Like WhatsApp?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

I am implementing push notifications, which I turn into local notifications in my iOS application.

When the iPhone is **locked** (Face ID / Touch ID) I see **only** the notification body which is "Notification" by default.

When the iPhone is **unlocked** (Face ID / Touch ID) I see the whole notification content.

I have tried to change the alert title to a hardcoded text.
Also tried to change the other properties, but I did not manage to solve it out.

This is how I create the local notification:

```c
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.userInfo = dictionary;
    [notification setAlertTitle:@"alertTitle"];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"alertBody"];
    
    [notification setFireDate:[NSDate date]];
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

What I want is - to show the title of the notification despite the locked state of the device, just like WhatsApp does.

#### Unlocked state

[image: Unlocked]

#### Locked state

[image: Locked]

As you can see, with the same settings - WhatsApp does show the title even though the iPhone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you let the user set this for each app. Go to *system settings > Your app > Notifications > Show Previews > Always*.
Note that you also have a default setting you can change that affects all apps you haven't explicitly configured. Go to *system settings > Notifications > Show Previews* to change that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this is not the wanted outcome. I don't want to show the whole message, just to add a title to the notifications when the iPhone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

`UILocalNotification` is deprecated. You should use the `UserNotifications` framework instead.

The notification content is managed by the `UNNotificationContent` user which has a `subtitle` property in addition to the `title` and `body` properties. I'm pretty sure the `subtitle` property is the one that shows when the phone is locked.